# Generating array with arrayjob and store values for further analysis

Tags: programming

In a two-dimensional array I want to store some calculated values. However, for example for a 2 on 2 matrix I get identical values for [1,2] and [2,1]. What am I am doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fp}                                 % fp-package
\usepackage{forloop,arrayjobx}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\CreateArray}[2]{
\FPeval\maxi{1+#1} \FPeval\maxj{1+#2}
\FPclip\maxi{\maxi} \FPclip\maxj{\maxj} 
\newcounter{i} \newcounter{j}
\newarray\MatrixA
\expandarrayelementtrue

When I set up the matrix everything works fine:

\forloop{i}{1}{\thei < \maxi}{                  % Rows
    \forloop{j}{1}{\thej < \maxj}{              % Columns
        \FPeval\calcvar{\thej+100*\thei}        % use variables i and j for calculation
        \FPclip\calcvar{\calcvar}
        \MatrixA(\thei,\thej)={\calcvar}        % save \calcvar value in matrix     
        \FPprint{\thei} - \FPprint{\thej} - \FPprint{\calcvar} \\
    }
}

But once I want to se the values stored the fields [2,1] and [1,2] are identical:

\forloop{i}{1}{\thei < \maxi}{                  % Rows
    \forloop{j}{1}{\thej < \maxj}{              % Columns
        \thei - \thej - \MatrixA(\thei,\thej) \\        
    }
}
}
\CreateArray{2}{2}                                  % crete matrix
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround but still I am interested in your suggestions for a solution of the initial problem.
I found out that lists are working just fine, so I decided to use a long list while for every "i" I just go 1000 entries higher and start save my entries at "i*1000+j".
This may work even for multidimensional arrays depending on the maximum length one list may have. 
Still this is not the solution I was looking for and hope that you can help me to get better code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fp}                                 % fp-package
\usepackage{forloop,arrayjobx}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\CreateArray}[2]{
    \FPset\jump{1000}                               % array as long list, max \jump values per column
    \FPeval\maxi{1+#1} \FPclip\maxi{\maxi} 
    \FPeval\maxj{1+#2} \FPclip\maxj{\maxj} 
    \newcounter{i} \newcounter{j} \newarray\MatrixA
    \expandarrayelementtrue
    \forloop{i}{1}{\thei < \maxi}{                  % Rows
        \forloop{j}{1}{\thej < \maxj}{              % Columns
            \FPeval\iloc{1+\thei*\jump-\jump} \FPclip\iloc{\iloc}
            \FPeval\calcvar{\thej+100*\thei}        
            \FPclip\calcvar{\calcvar}
            \MatrixA(\iloc,\thej)={\calcvar}        % save rsults in MatrixA Matrix     
            %           \FPprint{\thei} - \FPprint{\thej} -      
\FPprint{\calcvar} \\ % Testausgabe
        }
    }
    \forloop{i}{1}{\thei < \maxi}{                  % Rows
        \forloop{j}{1}{\thej < \maxj}{              % Columns
            \FPeval\iloc{1+\thei*\jump-\jump} \FPclip\iloc{\iloc}
            \thei - \thej - \MatrixA(\iloc,\thej) \\        
        }
    }
}
\CreateArray{3}{3}                                  % Matrix with {rows}{columns} 

\MatrixA(1,1)       \MatrixA(1,2)   \MatrixA(1,3)       \\
\MatrixA(1001,1)    \MatrixA(1001,2) \MatrixA(1001,3)   \\
\MatrixA(2001,1)    \MatrixA(2001,2) \MatrixA(2001,3)

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \forloop{i}{1}{\thei < \maxi}{                  % Rows
        \forloop{j}{1}{\thej < \maxj}{              % Columns
            \FPeval\iloc{1+\thei*\jump-\jump} \FPclip\iloc{\iloc}
            \MatrixA(\iloc,\thej)       
        }
        \\
    }
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `\dataheight=2` (corresponding to `\maxj`), which needs to be inserted prior to the nested `forloop`s that perform the initial assignments.

To be clear, modify the following part by adding `\dataheight=2`

```
When I set up the matrix everything works fine:
\dataheight=2
\forloop{i}{1}{\thei < \maxi}{                  % Rows
    \forloop{j}{1}{\thej < \maxj}{              % Columns
        \FPeval\calcvar{\thej+100*\thei}        % use variables i and j for calculation
        \FPclip\calcvar{\calcvar}
        \MatrixA(\thei,\thej)={\calcvar}        % save \calcvar value in matrix     
        \FPprint{\thei} - \FPprint{\thej} - \FPprint{\calcvar} \\
    }
}
```

I had a very similar problem ("[Why does arrayjobx return the wrong elements of the bi-dimensional matrix I defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440449/why-does-arrayjobx-return-the-wrong-elements-of-the-bi-dimensional-matrix-i-defi/%22Why%20does%20arrayjobx%20return%20the%20wrong%20elements%20of%20the%20bi-dimensional%20matrix%20I%20defined?%22)") and [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) solved it with the same advice I'm giving you.