# Why does arrayjobx return the wrong elements of the bi-dimensional matrix I defined?

Tags: programming

In the following MWE, I use package `arrayjobx` to define a 2x3 array `\RowPayoffs`, where I assign each element its value by referencing its (row, column). Specifically, I define `\RowPayoffs(i,j)={Rij}`, for each `(i,j): i \in {1,2}, j \in {1,2,3}`. I then query what value is actually in each element.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\newarray\RowPayoffs
\begin{document}
\RowPayoffs(1,1)={R11}
\RowPayoffs(1,2)={R12}
\RowPayoffs(1,3)={R13}
\RowPayoffs(2,1)={R21}
\RowPayoffs(2,2)={R22}
\RowPayoffs(2,3)={R23}
\noindent
\verb+\RowPayoffs(1,1) = +\RowPayoffs(1,1) \\
\verb+\RowPayoffs(1,2) = +\RowPayoffs(1,2) \\
\verb+\RowPayoffs(1,3) = +\RowPayoffs(1,3) \\
\verb+\RowPayoffs(2,1) = +\RowPayoffs(2,1) \\
\verb+\RowPayoffs(2,2) = +\RowPayoffs(2,2) \\
\verb+\RowPayoffs(2,3) = +\RowPayoffs(2,3)
\end{document}
```

This yields the following output:

[image]

My puzzle: When I query what value is in each `\RowPayoffs(i,j)`, not all of them are correct. Specifically, `\RowPayoffs(1,2)=R21` and `\RowPayoffs(1,3)=R22`.

Any ideas what's causing this serious problem? Or, alternatively, what is my severe misunderstanding of what the proper behavior should be?

In addition to the MWE here, I also tried this with `\normalindextrue` and `\normalindexfalse`, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `\dataheight`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\newarray\RowPayoffs
\begin{document}
\RowPayoffs(1,1)={R11}
\RowPayoffs(1,2)={R12}
\RowPayoffs(1,3)={R13}
\RowPayoffs(2,1)={R21}
\RowPayoffs(2,2)={R22}
\RowPayoffs(2,3)={R23}

\noindent
\verb+\RowPayoffs(1,1) = +\RowPayoffs(1,1) \\
\verb+\RowPayoffs(1,2) = +\RowPayoffs(1,2) \\
\verb+\RowPayoffs(1,3) = +\RowPayoffs(1,3) \\
\verb+\RowPayoffs(2,1) = +\RowPayoffs(2,1) \\
\verb+\RowPayoffs(2,2) = +\RowPayoffs(2,2) \\
\verb+\RowPayoffs(2,3) = +\RowPayoffs(2,3)

\bigskip

\dataheight=3
\RowPayoffs(1,1)={R11}
\RowPayoffs(1,2)={R12}
\RowPayoffs(1,3)={R13}
\RowPayoffs(2,1)={R21}
\RowPayoffs(2,2)={R22}
\RowPayoffs(2,3)={R23}

\noindent
\verb+\RowPayoffs(1,1) = +\RowPayoffs(1,1) \\
\verb+\RowPayoffs(1,2) = +\RowPayoffs(1,2) \\
\verb+\RowPayoffs(1,3) = +\RowPayoffs(1,3) \\
\verb+\RowPayoffs(2,1) = +\RowPayoffs(2,1) \\
\verb+\RowPayoffs(2,2) = +\RowPayoffs(2,2) \\
\verb+\RowPayoffs(2,3) = +\RowPayoffs(2,3)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This fixes it. I had seen that section of the manual but didn't appreciate that `\normalindexfalse`/`\normalindextrue` requires `\dataheight`. I was mislead by "The arrays can be mono or bi-dimensional and they are dynamically allocated (so we do not have to declare their dimension statically.)" I thought that specifying `\dataheight` in effect declares statically one of the dimensions.